# Prove that every $T_1$-space is $T_0$-space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> **Exercise**: A topological space is said to be $T_0$-space if for each pair of distinct points $a,b$ in $X$, either there exists an open set containing $a$ and not $b$, or there exists an open set containing $b$ and not $a$.A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be $T_1$-space if every singleton set $\{x\}$ is closed in  $(X,\tau)$
>
> Prove that every $T_1$-space is $T_0$-space.

I attempted the following proof:

If we have two topological spaces $T_1=(X,\tau_1)$ and $T_0=(X,\tau_0)$.
If $a,b\in X$, by the definition of $T_1$-space: $B=X\setminus{a}$ is an open set such that $a\notin B $ and $b\in B$. In analogous way $A=X\setminus{b}$ is an open set such that $b\notin A $ and $a\in A$. This proves that the open sets of $\tau_0 $are the open sets of $\tau_1$, then $\tau_0\subset\tau_1$.

**Question**:

Is the proof right? Can it be said  "open sets of $\tau_0 $are the open sets of $\tau_1$, then $\tau_0\subset\tau_0$"?

Comment: Why do you have two different topological spaces in your proof?

Comment: @bitesizebo                  Because the question refers to two different spaces and the underlying topologies define two different topological spaces regardless of the fact $X$ is the same set fro both.

Comment: Your proof shows that the space you are calling $T_1$ is by definition a $T_0$-space.  It does nothing to relate the open sets of the topological space $T_1$ to the open sets of the topological space $T_0$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan              $A,B$ as defined, are sets of $\tau_0$.

Comment: Right, so where you're getting confused is that $T_0$ and $T_1$ are not distinct spaces. They're *properties* of topological spaces, like being Hausdorff. You're given that the topological space $(X, \tau)$ satisfies the $T_1$ property. You need to prove that the same space also satisfies the $T_0$ property.

Comment: The exercise asks you to prove that “if $(X,\tau)$ is a $T_1$ space, then $(X,\tau)$ is a $T_0$ space”. There aren't two topologies involved.

Comment: It makes sense to consider $A,B$ as sets in either of the spaces $T_0$, $T_1$ you define but $A,B$ need only be open in the space $T_1$ (since you assume that it is a $T_1$-space).  Having no assumptions about how the bases $\tau_0$ and $\tau_1$ relate, you have no idea whether $A,B$ are open in $T_0$.  I think @bitesizebo has articulated where the confusion is arising.

Comment: @BadamBaplan            They are open in $T_0$ because they satisfy the condition of an open set in $\tau_0$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan                 $a\notin B $ and $b\in B$ and  $b\notin A $ and $a\in A$

Comment: In your $T_0$-space you do not know that points are closed, and equivalently you do know that the complement of points are open.  Thus you do not know that $A,B$ are in $\tau_0$.

Comment: In general, it is impossible to use the extent of separation of one topology on $X$ to reason about the extent of separation of another.   This is clear because we can always consider $X$ with the discrete topology, which satisfies *all* of the separation axioms, and with the particular point topology, which satisfies $T_0$ but not $T_1$ (so long as $X$ has more than two points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that  $(X,\tau) $ is $T_1$ space.

$\iff$ $\{x\}$ is a closed subset of $X$ for all $x\in X$

$\iff$  $\forall y\in \{x\}^c  $ $ \exists U_y \in \tau: y\in U_y\subset\{x\}^c $ for all $x\in X$

$\Rightarrow$ For all $y\neq x$ in $X$ there is an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $y\in U$,  $x\notin U$

$\Rightarrow$  $(X,\tau) $ is $T_0$ space.

Answer (score 2):

If every singleton is closed, then given $a \neq b \in X$, the set $X \, \backslash \, \{ a \}$ is an open subset of $X$ containing $b$ and not $a$.

Comment: That is what I meant in my proof.